# Replacing T12 flourescent bulbs

Tags: light-fixture

Can I replace my T12 fluorescent bulbs using LED tubes from Eled lights.com by just removing the ballast, or do I need to change any fittings?

How do I rewire the fixture if I remove the ballast?

Comment: I can't vouch for those particular tubes. Some require rewiring the fixture, some reportedly don't. Check with the manufacturer and/or the store to get instructions for this particular product. (I'm seriously considering just replacing the fixtures.)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your type of fixture. Go to there site and look and the install instructions and go with the ballast you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a T12 fixture  [this article](http://Non-Shunted%20Rapid%20Start%20Tombstones%20like%20this%20are%20needed.) indicates you are good to go.

A wiring diagram [is archived here](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0002/0948/files/Thinklux_Lighting_Bypass_T8_tube_installation_instruction.pdf?1439300417962171983).

Always consult and heed the instructions that come with the LED bulbs.